# How to Calculate Total Duration of Multiple Video Clips?

Tags: windows-7, windows, video

I am looking for method or a program (Windows XP or 7) that will allow me to select multiple video clips (or a folder) and tell me the total duration of all the video clips combined.

When I export video clips from my video camera, I end up with directories of small "scenes" running from a few seconds to several minutes. But there are hundreds of them per project, sometimes organized in several directories.

I'm looking for a quick way to display much video I have in a directory or project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up the Library pane of Windows Media Player (at least on v10), and then drag and drop the video files.

You should then see the Estimated Time of all the files reflect the sum of all the video and any other media you have sitting in the library pane.

[image: WMP Library calculation]

Answer (score 14):

This is what I do to know the length of set of videos:

Step 1:
Select all videos whose total length is to be known >> then right-click , go to `properties`.

[image: Step 1 screenshot]

Step 2:
After clicking `properties`, another small pop-up window opens with `General` & `Details` tabs.  Click `Details` tab.

Voila, there is a property field named `length`, with the corresponding value of your total video length.

[image: Step 2 and result screenshot]

P.S - Works with Windows 7 and 10. May work in windows 8.

Answer (score 2):

I remember that [WinAmp](http://www.winamp.com/) used to tell you the duration of a playlist (which can include videos), but that was probably a dozen versions ago, so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting all related media, right click on one, and go to properties->details and check length attribute.I tried this on Windows 8 though.

Answer (score 1):

VLC media player can show the total playback time. Drag and drop video files and see the total time on the "Playlist" pane

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Lister](https://web.archive.org/web/20130905024144/http://www.xyster.net/lister/index.php) (Wayback Machine link). This simple app lists many pieces of information about video/audio clips, including the duration. You can easily add the durations in a spreadsheet app.

<sup>1 Wayback Machine link</sup>

Currently (as of version 0.8), the following formats are supported:

- mp3, mp2 (common extensions: .mp3, .mp2)
- MPEG (common extensions: .mpg, .mpeg, .mpe)
- AVI (common extension: .avi)
- Ogg Vorbis (common extension: .ogg)
- RealAudio, RealVideo (common extensions: .ra, .rm)
- Microsoft Advanced Streaming Format (common extension: .asf)
- Microsoft Windows Media Audio (common extension: .wma)
- Microsoft Windows Media Video (common extension: .wmv)
- Twin-VQ (common extension: .vqf)
- Playlist files (common extensions: .pls, .b4s, m3u)

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the total duration of multiple videos, you can select all videos and calculate the video running time in your calculator, then you can get the total video time duration.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).